How can I instantiate an object on all tiles of a hexagonal tilemap?
On startup, I want to instantiate a text object on each tile (displaying its info). How can I accomplish this for a hexagonal tilemap?
Here's my poorly written code that doesn't work. It seems to create the right number of objects but I'm not sure how to get the correct positioning.
for (int x = 0; x < cellBounds.size.x; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < cellBounds.size.y; y++) {
            TMP_Text tileText = Instantiate(tileTextPrefab, tileUI.transform);
            tileText.text = dict[new Vector3(x,y,0)].getName();
            float hexOffset = 0f;
            if(y %2 != 0) hexOffset = cellSize.x * 0.5f;
            tileText.transform.position = new Vector3(x * cellSize.x + hexOffset, y * cellSize.y, 0);
        }
    } 


If it's not putting it in the right place, where is it putting it instead? Can you show us screenshots of the issue? Looking at the code, we can only guess. Your algorithm looks correct to me if the hex map is drawn on the XY plane and its bottom left corner is at (0, 0), otherwise you'd need to project the coordinates you're calculating out of the hexgrid's local space.
